# Symfony 3 Method 'guessExtension()' and 'move()' not found

Tags: php, symfony

So I've been trying to upload multiple files and store their locations. To set the new filenames I tried using guessExtension() method as described in symfony documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html and for some reason this method as well as move() method are not being recognized as seen in this image. What's going on with this? I've tried including Symfony's File and UploadedFile classes but that didn't solve the issue.

AutoController.php

```
        if($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted())
    {
        $powerType = $form['power_type']->getData();

        if($powerType == 'kw')
        {
            $auto->setPowerKw($form['powerKw']->getData());
            $auto->setPowerHp(ceil($form['powerKw']->getData() * 1.34));
        }
        else if($powerType == 'ag')
        {
            $auto->setPowerKw(ceil($form['powerKw']->getData() * 0.746));
            $auto->setPowerHp($form['powerKw']->getData());
        }

        // PLACEHOLDER
        $auto->setActive(true);
        // PLACEHOLDER

        // File uploading
        $files = $auto->getImages();
        $images = array();

        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

            $file->move(
                $this->getParameter('carAdds_directory'),
                $fileName
            );
            $images[$fileName] = $fileName;
        }

        $auto->setImages($images);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($auto);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('@Auto/auto/index.html.twig');
    }
```

Entity class

```
   /**
* @var array
*
* @Assert\Image(
*     mimeTypes = {
*   "image/png",
*   "image/pjpeg",
*   "image/jpeg",
*   "image/gif"
* },
*     mimeTypesMessage="Failas yra netinkamo formato",
*     maxSize = "10M",
*     maxSizeMessage="Failas yra per didelis"
* )
* @ORM\Column(name="images", type="array")
*/
private $images;  /**
 * Set images
 *
 * @param array $images
 *
 * @return Auto
 */
public function setImages($images)
{
    $this->images = $images;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get images
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getImages()
{
    return $this->images;
}
```

FormType class

```
            $builder->add('images', FileType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
            'label_attr' => array('class' => $label_offset),
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => $styles,
                'multiple' => 'multiple')))...
```

*EDIT
Okay, it does seems like this was just Php storm not recognizing the methods since I got no compiler errors, however the images are not being uploaded. 
[Here's what my database field look like after form submission is complete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2h9h.png)

config.yml

```
    carAdds_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/web/uploads/carAdds'
```

Php storm says Cannot find declaration to go to. Could this be the issue why my files don't seem to be uploaded and if so how do I properly specficy the path?

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually getting an error when executing the code or is it just the autocompletion in Symfony? If it is the latter:

```
/** @var File $file */
foreach($files as $file)
    {
...
```

should do the trick (you can actually type /** and PHPStorm will autocomplete the rest).

Comment: Turns out it was just autocompletion, however the images don't seem to be uploaded anywhere after form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Ignote that alert in your editor, it will still works.

PhpStorm somehow can't find the methods while they do exists.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that it was just PhpStorm since I didn't got any errors when running the code, however the images don't seem to be uploaded anywhere.

Comment: About that, I made a complete post on upload, read it, it might help you figure out something. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/38945180/6711360

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so thanks to Preciel's post https://stackoverflow.com/a/38945180/6711360 about file upload it turns out that instead of specifying my upload directory like:

```
carAdds_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/web/uploads/carAdds'
```

I had to specify it like this

```
carAdds_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/carAdds'
```

However this only works when I have my $images parameter in my entity class set to string, but I want to upload multiple pictures at the same time, so when I set $images type to array I get an empty array every time. Here's what my database field look like after form submission is complete.

[image: Here's what my database field look like after form submission is complete.]