# Symfony 3 upload file - FileNotFoundException

Tags: file, symfony, file-upload

Today i was found strange thing in file upload via symfony 3. I was trying upload file this way:

```
 // get file
 $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('uploadedFile', null);

 // generate file name
 $fileName = $this->getNewFileName();

 // move file
 $uploadedFile->move($path, $fileName.".".$uploadedFile->guessExtension());
```

But i get `FileNotFoundException`...

So i must do this: (Move method `guessExtension` out, before method `move`)

```
 // get file
 $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('uploadedFile', null);

 // generate file name
 $fileName = $this->getNewFileName().".".$uploadedFile->guessExtension();

 // move file
 $uploadedFile->move($path, $fileName);
```

Can anybody explain why?

EDIT:

File i has from classic `<form>` with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` with `<input type="file">`

Comment: How do you provide your file? From an Entity form?

Comment: Question was updated.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942760/file-upload-with-symfony3-not-working/38945180#38945180), I made a full post on how to handle uploaded file in Symfony. The part about registering your service is outdate, but everything else is good

Comment: I have functional file upload. My point is only that exception in case where i using `guessExtension` in method `move`... In your post this method is 'out of move method' like in my second usecase...

Comment: @LajdákMarek: This usually suggests the file is in fact not there and one common cause for this could be a file size limitation which is by default set to `2MB` (within `php.ini`). Was your file larger than this?

Comment: @JovanPerovic no it was a little file something about 0.5MB and my setting on server is: `upload_max_filesize = 10M`